# Portable branch prediction hints

Tags: c++, c, optimization, c++20, branch-prediction

Is there any portable way of doing branch prediction hints? Consider the following example:

```
  if (unlikely_condition) {
    /* ..A.. */
  } else {
    /* ..B.. */
  }
```

Is this any different than doing:

```
  if (!unlikely_condition) {
    /* ..B.. */
  } else {
    /* ..A.. */
  }
```

Or is the only way to use compiler specific hints? (e.g. __builtin_expect on GCC)

Will compilers treat the `if` conditions any differently based on the ordering of the conditions?

Comment: I wonder whether this could be something C++0x attributes to stick on conditions for `if`? Like `if([[unlikely]] unlikely_condition) { ... }`? Currently the syntax does not allow it. It *does* however allow `if([[unlikely]] bool b = ...) { }`. Maybe one could abuse that :)

Comment: GNU code contains a ridiculous amount of `if(likely(...))` junk in completely non-performance-critical code, and IMO this is really bad. For one thing, it doesn't read naturally in English - it sounds like "if this condition is likely to be true" instead of "if this condition is true, which it likely is". And for another, it's just clutter. Unless you have lots of performance-critical conditionals that won't compile to `cmov` or similar already, just ignore branch prediction hinting.

Comment: @R.. I think I understand why the Linux kernel is littered with `if(unlikely(...))`. They prefer early exits that make code flow easier to follow. If they did not do this then the static branch prediction would always fail.

Comment: And it would make Linux 0.00001% slower. Not measurable. If it is, simply put this crap in the few conditionals where it is measurable, not everywhere.

Comment: It's also a kind of documental hint. I use it often to distinguish between active work code and exceptional error handling code. This said on the architecture I work on, it's a quite useful mechaism as the ISA has hint bits in the branch instruction (SPARC).

Comment: Oskar: I think @R.. was referring to glibc, which is, err... let's say not as nice to read as the Linux Kernel. But maybe it's just me, you know, everyone has different tastes.

Comment: @tristopia: MIPS also has something similar: branch likely instructions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The canonical way to do static branch prediction is that `if` is predicted not-branched (i.e. every `if` clause is executed, not `else`), and loops and backward-`goto`s are taken. So, don't put the common case in `else` if you expect static prediction to be significant. Getting around an untaken loop isn't as easy; I've never tried but I suppose putting it an an `else` clause should work pretty portably.

Many compilers support some form of `#pragma unroll`, but it will still be necessary to guard it with some kind of `#if` to protect other compilers.

Branch prediction hints can theoretically express a complete description of how to transform a program's flow-control graph and arrange the basic blocks in executable memory… so there are a variety of things to express, and most won't be very portable.

As GNU recommends in the documentation for `__builtin_expect`, profile-guided optimization is superior to hints, and with less effort.

Comment: And VS has PGO too, so it's a win-win. :)

Answer (score 21):

In most cases, the following code

```
if (a)
{
   ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

is actually

```
evaluate(A)

if (!A)
{
   jmp p1
}

... code A

   jmp p2

p1:

... code !A

p2:
```

Note that if A is true, "code A" is already in the pipeline. The processor will see the "jmp p2" command ahead, and will load p2 code to the pipeline.

If A is false, the "code !A" may not be in the pipleline, therefore it may be slower.

Conclusions:

1. do If(X) if X is more likely than !X
2. try to evaluate A as early as possible, so that the CPU can dynmically optimize the pipeline.

:

```
evaluate(A)

do more stuff

if (A)
   ...
```

Comment: got it! Please keep the 'if' code in braces pls -even though its single line. It's a bit confusing otherwise!

Comment: "try to evaluate A as early as possible, so that the CPU can dynmically optimize the pipeline." - Can you please provide some pointers for this statement? I want to know how it will do it.

Comment: A lot of information here: http://download.intel.com/design/pentiumii/manuals/24281603.pdf

Comment: @LiorKogan link is dead now. Any way to find it again?

Comment: @Carlos: yes. Google "Intel 24281603".

Answer (score 7):

Optimization is inherently a compiler thing, so you have to use compiler functionality to help it. The language itself doesn't care about (or mandate) optimizations.

So the best you can do *without* compiler-specific extensions is organize your code in such a way where your compilers will "do the right thing" without help. But if you want to be sure, tap in to compiler extensions. (You might try abstracting them behind the preprocessor, so your code remains portable.)

Comment: There's plenty of precedent for the language providing optimisation hints, though (`inline`, `restrict`, `register`). Some are more pointful than others on modern compilers. It doesn't matter whether a particular implementation actually does anything with them: if there's a reasonable chance of some doing something useful, then it would be a nice feature. I reckon static branch prediction in the main doesn't meet that criterion, so I don't think it's a bad call to leave it out. It is a judgement on the merits of the case, though, not quite "we don't care about optimisation, ever".

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, I guess I automatically ignore those so I forget about them. You're right.

Comment: I think `restrict` is probably worthwhile as a premature optimisation. It's not going to do any harm, it might do significant good by preventing horrible store/load dependencies, and where it applies it's presumably a documented requirement (as in `memcpy`) whether that's reflected in the source or not. The others (and in C++03), I agree with your resounding "meh" :-)

Comment: @Steve: I agree, I was ignoring `restrict` since it's not part of the current standard. :)

Comment: Ah, but this is one of those tagged-C-and-C++ questions, where even the simplest answer can disappear in a blizzard of caveats.

Comment: @Steve: Oh, I didn't even see that. :x

Answer (score 7):

C++20 offers [likely and unlikely attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely)

> Allow the compiler to optimize for the case where paths of execution
>   including that statement are more or less likely than any alternative
>   path of execution that does not include such a statement

Comment: This feature is [not yet available in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20), unfortunately.

Comment: @FranklinYu it seems Clang 12 supports this as per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support.

Comment: That’s a good news! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Just be consistant with what you do.  I like to use

```
if (!(someExpression))
```

But the compiler should treat this equally.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with checking for a specific compiler via `#ifdef` and hiding these things behind a custom macro? You can `#define` it to expand to the plain expression in cases you don't have a compiler that supports these optimization hints. I recently did something similar with explicit cache prefetches which GCC supports via an intrinsic function.

Comment: I've done that.  With more than two or three compilers it can become a real mess, if different compilers use different syntax.